# How to check if php://input is set?

Tags: php, input, wrapper, isset

I need to check if `php://input` exists/isset. Does it work with PHP [`isset()`](https://php.net/isset) ? What is the proper way to check it?

Comment: Look it's Schrodinger's Cat! You can't know it until you *f*open it! :)

Comment: If it's std web request, you can check for $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'], apart of that there's no other way. Functions like fstat or stream_get_meta_data doesn't work in this case. :(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try to test it with [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file-get-contents) (for reading) + [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) or [boolean conversion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) (for testing):

```
<?php
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');

if ($input) {
   // exists
} else {
   // not exists
}
```

***From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php):***

> **Note:** *Prior to PHP 5.6*, a stream opened with `php://input` could only be read once; the stream did not support seek operations. However, depending on the SAPI implementation, it may be possible to open another php://input stream and restart reading. This is only possible if the request body data has been saved. Typically, this is the case for POST requests, but not other request methods, such as PUT or PROPFIND.

Comment: In this case i`m reading base64 data from a file upload, file_get_contents only return something if it reads a true file? (i mean, if the user send a fake base64, just text, but pre formated to look like base 64, but not a true file, what would result from $input?)

Comment: @sagits yes. `file_get_contents()`, when using this URL-wrapper, reads any content, if it is there. No matter of content structure.

Comment: Thank your @CORRUPT, i got a little confused about your answer, you mean that it can read the fake base 64, but will return false, or it would return true? I read on the function manual that it returns false if it can`t read the content. Can you explain me that? Thank you for your time

Comment: @sagits it will return any content, except empty string (`''`), that was posted to `php://input`. I mean, if even fake base64 string would be there, it will return it as string.

Comment: Thank you, i`m going to use [base64_decode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.base64-decode.php) to check for error`s in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the contents of `php://input` using [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) and check the return value to see if it's actually set:

```
$input = file_get_contents("php://input");
if ($input) {    
    // set     
}
else {
   // not set
}
```

Comment: `isset()` will always return true in this scenario, use `!empty()` or just get rid of that condition.

Comment: `file_get_contents()` returns string on success.

Comment: @SamT: I think it's a good idea to check if `$input` is `TRUE` instead.

Comment: @AmalMurali I agree, strictly ;)

Answer (score 1):

it returns true if variable exist and its not null

```
$foo = 'bar';
var_dump(isset($foo));        -> true

$baz = null;
var_dump(isset($baz));        -> false

var_dump(isset($undefined));  -> false
```

Answer (score -2):

Suppose you are  getting  user input  from  a POST request  you can check if  it's a set like  this

```
 if(isset($_POST['var_name']))
 {
      //for additional checking  like if  it's not  empty do this
      if(!empty($_POST['var_name']))
      {
           //Do whatever you want here
      }
 }
```

Comment: `php://input` is where `POST` or `PUT` data is located, not `GET` parameters.

Comment: Better, although it will only work if the data is formatted properly as form data. Usually the reason to use `php://input` is because you need to access the raw data.

Comment: agreed  but i guess i just wanted to give an example of  how to use iseet function